# What are Blocks in Draftjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am going through the draftjs documentation and at a lot of places, 'block' word is used interchangeably. For ex.:

Within Editor, some **block types** are given default CSS styles to limit the amount of basic configuration required to get engineers up and running with custom editors.

I am trying to understand exactly what this block means at granular level, is it a snippet of text, or the whole editorState?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `editorstate` contains the `selectionstate` and `contentstate`. `contentstate` is composed by `blocks`. so a `block` is mainly a html paragraph with `id`, `type` and `data`. `id` is for identifying a paragraph. `type` is a little complex, but mainly there are two types, `atomic` and non-atomic, for non-editable paragraph(image/vide/...) and texts. `data` is for using you want store something to the block and use it later in any `draft` callbacks.

You may read docs more with patience, especially understand it by example codes.

Comment: I will take your word.. will go through the documentation once again. @Jiang YD thanks again.

Comment: Well, the Draft.js' documentation isn't the best when it comes to explaining the framework's abstractions. I myself did not fully understand that a block represents a paragraph after having read to docs twice. This question & answer are good and useful.